# Laravel adding database records automatic

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

When refreshing my database all the records are removed.

I have some records and tables that I need to run my app and they are the same every time.

Does laravel offer a way to code these and then a command to add them.

I would also like to do a similar thing for testing.

Thanks for any feedback

Comment: I've used [seeding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/seeding) for this kind of thing before.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel offers strong tools for this kind of thing, which is commonly known as database seeding. It even has helpers for creating lots of fake data for common items such as email addresses, postal addresses, names etc out of the box.

See the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/seeding) on Laravel's website for a usage guide.

Answer (score 0):

Seeding would definitely be the way to go here!

It's super simple and you can read more about it here
https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/seeding

In case you just need some random for another time you can use seeding factories, which is super nice aswell, for example to insert users, tasks or whatever you need.

One thing i missed when i read the docs was this one

```
php artisan migrate:refresh --seed
```

Super nice when codeing so you dont have to repat your command lines.